# Tooling API SymbolTable contains "private" visibility modifiers instead of "protected"

Tags: apex, tooling-api, access-modifier

When I query **SymbolTable** using **Tooling API** there are not any **protected** modifiers at all! Every **protected** word is replaced with **private**. The field **classBody** shows  all **protected** keywords as they are but **SymbolTable** doesn't show any of them.

What is the reason for that? Is that a bug or it has some sense?

Comment: Have you logged a case with Salesforce Support?

Comment: I can't open an issue because I have only developer edition account. Or do you mean something else? I would like to do something like that but don't know how.

Comment: No, you're right. If you're not a Salesforce customer or partner, I don't think you'll be able to log a case. :-(

Comment: Even if you are a partner but without premier support, they close the case if it's related to development. Sounds like a bug. Would be great if someone with PS could report it.

Comment: I see you've raised the question on the [developer forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AsQtIAK). I've found support will usually get back to you in a week (or month...). It is a frustratingly slow way to raise a platform bug/issue, but it usually pays off if you are persistent.

Answer (score 6):

**Update from Salesforce support:**

> I checked with R&D regarding this, and they are releasing an enhancement to allow all modifiers in the next version of the API, which is 34 (Summer '15). -Shashank
>    [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AsQtIAK)

---

It appears that at the API level `protected` isn't supported.

Extract from the Tooling API v32.0 WSDL:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SymbolVisibility">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="Global"/>
  <xsd:enumeration value="Public"/>
  <xsd:enumeration value="Private"/>
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Note the absence of `protected`. It can't be returned, so it appears they send back `private` instead.

You also see hints of this in the documentation for [SymbolTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_symboltable.htm):

[image: SymbolTable visibility options]

It does seem odd the protected isn't represented, as it is valid in Apex [access modifier](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm).

Comment: Yeah I noticed this part in documentation later. Either it's odd or it has some meaning that we don't  understand.

Comment: I suspect it will take someone inside Salesforce to answer the why of it. A couple of guesses: 1) They based the API on what access modifiers were allowed for a constructor and did a hack work around for protected properties rather than add in protected. 2) protected access modifiers have some sort of odd internal representation that gets lost in the transition to a SymbolTable.

Comment: I work at Salesforce and can look into this. Curious to know myself. 

Querying ApexClass is a possible workaround, but requires parsing the Body:

SELECT Id, Name, Body FROM ApexClass

Comment: @dlog Thanks, I'd be interested to know what comes of it.